# Expected behaviour of .after method on disconnected DOM elements in jQuery 1.9.1

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom

I'm constructing disconnected DOM elements using jQuery 1.9.1 using the following type of construct:

```
$("<div/>").after("<p></p>");
```

According to the documentation (http://api.jquery.com/after/), this is supposed to return a jQuery set consisting of a div and paragraph in that order. Instead, I'm just getting a div. I've found at least two bug reports that refer to behaviour like this - http://bugs.jquery.com/ticket/8759 and http://bugs.jquery.com/ticket/10517 - but both are allegedly fixed in 1.9.1. Is this case? Or am I misunderstanding how this method is supposed to work on disconnected elements?

Comment: @dfsq Sorry, but you're way off. Creating a disconnecting element should create a nodefragment, when using .after() on a nodefragment, you should create another nodefragment, but instead it's walking past it. Walk through an unminified jQuery version and see it for yourself. Blind comment imo.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [jQuery 1.9 Upgrade Guide](http://jquery.com/upgrade-guide/1.9/#after-before-and-replacewith-with-disconnected-nodes) says that disconnected nodes do not have any special-case handling in `.after()` anymore, it just hasn't made it into the main documentation yet. The bugs you mention were just the tip of the iceberg as far as special cases go.

Not sure what the use case is, but if you're creating several disconnected elements over time and want them to be in a specific order then create them in a plain old JavaScript array and append them all at once. You can still use jQuery to create them if you want.

`var x = [ $("<div/>")[0], $("<p/>")[0] ]; $(x).appendTo("body");`